# Can knit to pdf but not run chunks with knitr::kable

Tags: r, r-markdown

I can knit my .Rmd file to HTML and PDF but I can't run separate chunks that contain `knitr::kable()`. The problem is really strange since it's possible to create a PDF containing all the chunks but not run one of the chunks separately. When I try to run the chunk in question I get the error message below.

```
knitr::kable(df, digits = 6, caption = "Parameterskattningar för niter=1,2,3 och R's summary()")
```

Error message:

> Error in system(command) : invalid input
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\RStudio\bin\pandoc\pandoc.exe +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   "C:\Users\MAXSJD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCKdLUS_rs_md_1ad85bc13dd1.md"
>   --to html4 --output "C:\Users\Max Sjödin\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop\notebooks\878C31A-Lab 1 Stat
>   inferens\1\s\csrh4amtwagyp_t_rs_html_1ad82c5879bb.html"' in
>   'utf8towcs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the ö character in the path to your RStudio project file. I had some issues when I create a script on an English Windows and then try to edit it on a Portuguese Windows version.
I would love to see a more complete answer with a good explanation to why this happens, but this can maybe get things working for the time being.

Comment: I add the same problem, and removing European character (like ê) from the path made the trick. Thanks @Thiago

Comment: Is there any solution that works without changing the path?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem `knitr::kable()`. It occurred after I reinstalled the R to fresher version (3.5.2). The old one was 3.4.3.

What I did, just went back to the old one (may it sound stupid), and it worked.